# Prevent systemd-cgtop help menu from disappearing

Tags: systemd

When I start `systemd-cgtop` so I press the `?` key, then I want to read the help menu but it disappears after a couple seconds. How do I keep the help menu from disappearing?

Comment: `Ctrl-S` will send `SIGSTOP` to `systemd-cgtop`, and it will stop updating the output. To unfreeze it back, use `Ctrl-Q`.

Comment: @DanilaKiver if you make this an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ctrl-S` will send `SIGSTOP` to `systemd-cgtop`, and it will stop updating the output. To unfreeze it back, use `Ctrl-Q`.